# Error importing testng xml report to jira xray

Tags: selenium, testng, jira, jira-xray

when i try importing testng xml report to xray jira manualy/automation its throwing error

"Error importing Execution results Error creating tests in jira with following error

Project Name is required

```
{
    "error": "Error creating tests in Jira with the following error(s): Project Name is required."
}
```

https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/import/execution/testng?projectKey=TM&testExecKey=TM-3563

[due to this custom label report is not getting added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvNK8.png)

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFLgb.png)

Note-project name i have alreadry added in UI

[JIRA ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4IH1.png)

Comment: Can you please provide further details?
1) Are you using Xray on Jira Cloud or on Jira server/datacenter (on-premises)?
2) how are you submiting the results? Using the REST API directly? Can you provide the exact HTTP request you did?

Comment: {
    "error": "Error creating tests in Jira with the following error(s): Project Name is required."
}

https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/import/execution/testng?projectKey=TM&testExecKey=TM-3563

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your error is caused by the way you're invoking the REST API or maybe the projectKey is not correct (you need to use the project's key and not its name).

It's not clear exactly how you submited the report file but you can use a bash script to submit your results as follows.
In this example, you will need to have an auxiliary file with your api key credentials, having something like:
{ "client_id": "215FFD69FE460000000000","client_secret": "2c00f8f22f56a8684d7518cd6147ce278700000000000000000000" }

Then you can execute the following script (copy it to a file named submit.sh, for example).

```
PROJECT=TM
TESTPLAN=
BROWSER=
token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @"cloud_auth.json" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/authenticate| tr -d '"')
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml" "https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v2/import/execution/testng?projectKey=$PROJECT&testPlanKey=$TESTPLAN&testEnvironments=$BROWSER"
```

Comment: even if i am manually uploading the testng report .xml  through import execution UI its asking project name is missing

Comment: Do i have to add anything @Xray(ProjectName='QA')

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. Are you using @Xray annotation? if so, can you please share an example of the annotated test method?

Comment: the generated testng  report xml works fine in another jira which doesnot have signoff project name associated.. i have attached the screenshot(attached screenshot doesnot work if this is ascociated)

Comment: Is it possible to pass project name in testng report .xml

Comment: @rahulmohanty, no that's not possible.

Comment: In order to understand exaclty what is the problem you're facing, we would need a bit more details, like the code snippet that you're using and the generate test report. My suggestion instead would be this: can you try following perhaps this tutorial? Maybe it can help out, as it provides a concrete example for TestNG.

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+TestNG+in+Java